# How to load view from subfolder in zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, directory-structure

I can't find out how my controllers to load views from subfolders in view directory. My controllers are organized in subfolders in controller folder and i want each controller to load it's view from corresponding subfolder in view. When i go to IndexController in Admin subfolder zend ignores admin folder and searches for a view application/index/index instead of application/admin/index/index. 
Here is my directory structure

```
/module
    /Application
        /config
        /src
            /Application
                /Controller
                    /Admin
                        IndexController.php
                    IndexController.php
                /Form
                /Model
        /view
            /application
                /admin
                    /index
                        index.phtml                     
                /index
                    index.phtml
```

Comment: I don't understand why you not use default modular approach instead of reinventing another approach. In another works you only need to define another Admin module and move your all admin controllers into there. In current approach, you need to move your whole project in just in Application folder i think.

Comment: it doesnt standard module directory structure

Comment: look at this PR https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/5670 That will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can change the template path of your view like this :

```
$view = new ViewModel() 

...

...

$view->setTemplate('path/to/my/view.phtml');`
```

or in your config :

```
'view_manager' => array(

....

'template_path_stack' => array( 'path/to/your/folder/template'),
```

Comment: You shouldn't use  /Admin/IndexController.php like that, it's better to have another controller like this : /Application/Controller/AdminindexController.php